# How to create a UWP application which only opens a specific url

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to create a UWP application which only opens a specific url in the browser. So I mean that this app will have an icon in the start menu but when a user clicks this icon nothing happens but only my url is opened in the browser. Is it possible? How to implement such UWP application?
I created an App class and in OnLaunched method I wrote this code:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    var task = Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("https://stackoverflow.com")).AsTask();
    task.Wait();
    CoreApplication.Exit();
}
```

This works fine. The only problem is that white window of my app is opened and closed after about 1 second.

**Update 1:**
The main purpose of my app is to work as an appservice. Another component of my system successfully communicates with it. If it is possible not to show the icon in the start menu at all it would be great solution. However, I don't know how to hide my app from the start menu. So another appropriate solution for me is just to open the url of my specific web site without showing a splash window once a user clicks the icon in the start menu.
I don't care about certification in the store.

Comment: Why you use  CoreApplication.Exit();  end of the function.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the purpose of your app then?

Comment: Why are you re-inventing the wheel? Browsers can do that for you.

Comment: You can explain your need in detail as this kind of app will not be certified by store.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you can successfully implement such behavior, the app window and splash screen will still display (even if just for a while) and the app will definitely not pass Microsoft Store submission (because it exits during launch and it brings no additional value over the website itself)

Comment: @Oleg Ignatov If this has resolved your issue, please consider accepting the answer as solution so that the question is resolved.